# npm run build:ssr does not work in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular8

I use angular 8 and server-side-rendering but i got error when i run `npm run build:ssr`
As you can see, `src` is repeated twice `home/app/front/**src/src**/main.server.ts`

I tried everything without success. I move main.server.ts and i created a new src but no succes.

`angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "front-end": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
             
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js",
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "fr": {
              "aot": true,
              "outputPath": "dist/my-project-fr/",
              "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "fr"
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "front-end:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "fr": {
              "browserTarget": "front-end:build:fr"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "front-end:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "front-end:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": false,
                "styles": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "front-end-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "front-end:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "front-end",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run front-end:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@material/icon-button": "^0.43.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "@uiowa/digit-only": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.14.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "error-stack-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "image-base64": "^1.0.2",
    "image-to-base64": "^2.0.1",
    "intl-tel-input": "^15.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-material-multilevel-menu": "^4.10.8",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.3.0",
    "ng2-img-max": "^2.1.18",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-avatar": "^3.7.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^7.2.4",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^2.3.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-show-hide-password": "^2.0.3",
    "object-to-formdata": "^1.6.4",
    "rollbar": "^2.5.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
    "stacktrace-parser": "^0.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.802.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

and my app folder

**ERROR**:

```
ERROR in error TS6053: File '/home//Desk/app/front/src/src/main.server.ts'
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message do you get when you run the command?

Comment: ERROR in error TS6053: File '/home//Desk/app/front/src/src/main.server.ts' not found.

Comment: what if you change it to `./src/main.server.ts` or `main.server.ts` or `/src/main.server.ts`

Comment: I have the same error

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you solve this @user9714967?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the same error. This is how i solved it:

In `src/tsconfig.server.json`

Change `src/main.server.ts` to `main.server.ts`

Comment: I had to do this, and also change `server.ts` to `../server.ts`

Comment: Me too. Also the ```server.ts``` to ```../server.ts```

Comment: Not able to find out tsconfig.server.json

Comment: Still getting the same error after changing the directory, in Angular 12

Answer (score 2):

In file `src/tsconfig.server.json` (generated by `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject myProject` ) I changed

`"files": [ "src/main.server.ts", "server.ts" ],`

into

`"files": [ "main.server.ts", "../server.ts" ],`

After that `npm run build:ssr` works fine.

Answer (score -2):

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

run this command from inside your application folder

Comment: That package is already included in the package.json provided in the original question.