# angular SSR using @nguniversal/express-engine package get this error (ERROR in error TS6053: File '/project/src/server.ngtypecheck.ts' not found.)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, server-side-rendering

I am using @nguniversal/express-engine to Server Side Rendering in angular.When I run `$ nmp build:ssr` or `$ npm run dev:ssr` i get this error.

```
ERROR in error TS6053: File 'C:/dev/web/workspace/project/src/server.ngtypecheck.ts' not found.
error TS6053: File 'C:/dev/web/workspace/project/src/server.ts' not found.
error TS6053: File 'C:/dev/web/workspace/project/src/src/main.server.ngtypecheck.ts' not found.
error TS6053: File 'C:/dev/web/workspace/project/src/src/main.server.ts' not found.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.0.0 build:ssr: `ng build --prod && ng run client:server:production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.0.0 build:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: How did you added nguniversal ? And which version of angular is ?

Comment: @abhaytripathi  thanks for reply. i added nguniversal with `$ ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` and my angular version is 10.0.1

Comment: Than the above 4 files should be automatically generated.

Comment: Check if they are created or not.

Comment: @abhaytripathi which files? what is their name?

Comment: Check the first four lines of the given error code.

Comment: @abhaytripathi  `/server.ngtypecheck.ts` and `main.server.ngtypecheck.ts` not exist.

Comment: @abhaytripathi and `server.ts` exist in root not in `src/server.ts`. and `main.server.ts` exit in `src/main.server.ts` not in `/src/src/main.server.ts`

Comment: Can you add your angular.json file? that's where the links to your `main.ts` and `main.server.ts` are... I assume you have a typo there. I have `"projects:ClientApp:architect:build:options:main": "src/main.ts"` and `"projects:ClientApp:architect:server:options:main": "server.ts"`

Comment: @Pieterjan I checked. they are right.

Comment: Hard to tell where the `/src/src` is coming from, but I think it definitely shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the same issue, the doubling-up of `src/src` is occurring from tsconfig.server.json. I encountered this error running build:ssr for Angular, the solution as described here: [npm run build:ssr does not work in angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526907/npm-run-buildssr-does-not-work-in-angular-8) is quite simple. We need to edit the src/tsconfig.server.json.

I had to make two changes; both were described in that solution.

Navigate to `src/tsconfig.server.json`

- Change `src/main.server.ts` to `main.server.ts`,
- Change `server.ts` to `../server.ts`.

Props to the other thread for the solution really,